# Create file watcher that will restart websocket server when specific files modified

Tags: python, python-2.7, websocket, tornado

Having file `websocket_server.py` and `webscoket_service.py` to run websocket I do `python websocket_server.py`
How show I configure custom file watcher so when I modify `webscoket_service.py`, my websocket server being restarted

Answer (score 1):

You can simply pass `autoreload=True` or `debug=True` (which does autoreload and some other things) to your `Application` constructor.